# Sending Email in React Native

Tags: react-native, email

I am working on a React Native application. I need to send an email using an Email service, like an API. Can anyone please guide me through the process?

Comment: Are you familiar with Linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering this question myself to help others, providing them with an easy email service they might be looking for.

A third-party API provider that provides the email services, sandbox environment is also available for testing purposes. Here's the link for reference.

https://cloudinary.com/visualweb/display/IMMC/React+Native+Image+Upload

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario, you can use [Linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) in react native.

**Import this first**

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
```

**React Native Open Mail Function :**

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com') }
  title="support@example.com" />
```

**React Native Open Mail Function With Subject and Body**

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:support@example.com?subject=SendMail&body=Description') }
      title="support@example.com" />
```

**React Native Open URL**

```
<Button onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.co.in/') }
      title="www.google.co.in" />
```

**More Details :**

> mailto:?subject=&body=&cc=

`<receiver_email>`  Important value. The email address to send email.

`<subject>`  default email subject that will attach to new email (option)

`<body>`  default email text (option)

`<emails_to_copy>`  list of emails to copy (option)

**Example Full Code**

```
// send-email.js

// We can use react-native Linking to send email
import qs from 'qs';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';


export async function sendEmail(to, subject, body, options = {}) {
    const { cc, bcc } = options;

    let url = `mailto:${to}`;

    // Create email link query
    const query = qs.stringify({
        subject: subject,
        body: body,
        cc: cc,
        bcc: bcc
    });

    if (query.length) {
        url += `?${query}`;
    }

    // check if we can use this link
    const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

    if (!canOpen) {
        throw new Error('Provided URL can not be handled');
    }

    return Linking.openURL(url);
}


// example.js

import { sendEmail } from './send-email';

sendEmail(
    'test@gmail.com',
    'Greeting!',
    'I think you are fucked up how many letters you get.'
).then(() => {
    console.log('Our email successful provided to device mail ');
});
```

**For sending emails as background service :**

I think you need a e-mail server or atleast an email service to send an email with your app. I don't think you can send e-mails directly from the client side.

But there are various email services on the Internet that you can use for free (like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) or [SendPulse](https://sendpulse.com/). There you can just use a simple POST method from the code in your app against their APIs.

If you wan to send email using SMTP protocol then you can use the [react native smtp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp) module or [react-native-smtp-mailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-smtp-mailer). You can read about it from here.

Comment: It will open the mailbox and wait for me to send the email. Actually, I want to do it all in the background. I need to specify just the receiver as we do it in PHP's mail() function.

Comment: Please update your question with more details. Your question only says you want to send email as function only

Comment: react-native-smtp is just for Android.

Comment: Use this for iOS - https://github.com/angelos3lex/react-native-smtp-mailer